# django multi-table inheritance validation with the admin app

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-orm

When working with a Django Model with [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) set-up as in the docs, the admin app cannot add a new "Restaurant" model if a matching "Place" entry exists - the admin app returns "Place with this name already exists".

Django's [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation) provides methods for form validation, and the [Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.validate_unique) provides uniqueness validation.
Which is the best place to enable turning the existing Place entry into a Restaurant?
How would you do this?

For Example, a Place(name="hotdogshop", address="bond street") exists, and the user tries to add a Restaraunt( serves_hot_dogs=True, serves_pizza=False, name="hotdogshop", address="bond street" ).  The desired end result would be the same as if we had added the "hotdogshop" as a "Restaraunt" to begin with.

Comment: It seems that https://github.com/craigds/django-typed-models allows for recasting Model objects... current attempt is to hook into Model._perform_unique_checks and trigger a recast when uniqueness is violated.

Answer (score 0):

An initial hacky workaround is to insert an extra uniqueness check to the model verification, and switch to using [django-typed-models](https://github.com/craigds/django-typed-models) so we can recast models.

For example, add the following pseudo-code to your Model.

```
def _perform_unique_checks(self, unique_checks):

    print("Performing custom Recast Unique Check")

    try:
        # Search for any existing Model you want to replace.
        exists = MyModel.objects.get(...)
        if exists:
            # django-typed-models can be recast without affecting integrity.
            exist.recast('myApp.mySubclassedModel')
            # Pretend nothing went wrong, so the rest of the save process continues.
            return {}

    except TwitterHarvestedUser.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    return super()._perform_unique_checks(unique_checks)
```

Be careful around how you merge the data from the previous and new model.  Djangos save() method will by default end up replacing all the old models fields even if they are unchanged in the new model.

This doesn't work with MyModel.objects.create()